# How to set badge on push notification received in android and ios?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am trying to set badge count on app icon using react native firebase when push notification received on mobile. But unable to set value of count on app icon dynamically.

Here is my code -

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
  'demo',
  'DEMO',
  firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
).setDescription('DEMO APP');
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {

    const { title, body, id } = notification.data;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.id = id;

    const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
      sound: 'default',
      show_in_foreground: true,
    })
    .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
    .setTitle(notification.title)
    .setBody(notification.body)
    .setData(notification.data)
    .setBadge(notification.id)
    .android.setAutoCancel(true)
    .android.setChannelId('demo') // e.g. the id you chose above
    .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher') // create this icon in Android Studio
    .android.setColor('#000000') // you can set a color here
    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

    firebase.notifications()
    .displayNotification(localNotification)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
}
```

Please help anyone have solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

if anyone is still wondering here is how i achieved it

```
 firebase.notifications().setBadge(badgeCount);
```

Comment: Where i put this line?

Comment: @OliverD where you want to update the badge count and please note this is v5 of rnFirebase

Comment: I wanna do it in App icon, and inside the app in the header component, I have a notification icon ""

Comment: the above line will handle the app icon only and its support is all ios devices and some android devices since there are restriction there meanwhile regarding notification badge you need to set via state/redux etc

Comment: Thank you i solve notification badge inside the app, but badge icon does not appear with me in Android 8 by default so I use react native firebase v6 and I don't see any module relate to the notification so I can't use your line of code:( and I don't know how can I handle it

Comment: hey, I have used this, but in my case, in ios build,  it is working only when app is in the foreground. I have created an issue, please refer it https://stackoverflow.com/q/62528961/8980376 and help me to find the issue

Comment: How does one achieve the same with @react-native-firebase/messaging ?

Comment: This solution does not work for anyone using Firebase version above v5